# Delphi styled VCL TTrackBar: hide focus dotted rectangle while tracking

Tags: delphi, vcl, vcl-styles

How can I hide the focus around a VCL TTrackBar when selected/while tracking, while using a VCL style? Using Delphi 11.1

This didn't work:

```
SendMessage(tb1.Handle, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, UIS_SET OR UISF_HIDEFOCUS, 0);
```

[image]

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-updateuistate) reveals `UIS_SET` means "The UI state element specified by the high-order word should be visible." Exactly the opposite of what you want. Use `UIS_CLEAR` instead.

Comment: However, I believe the focus change, when pointing with mouse, overrules that setting anyway

Comment: Yes, no difference with UIS_CLEAR

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
SendMessage(tb1.Handle, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, UIS_CLEAR OR UISF_HIDEFOCUS, 0);
```

**does** work.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Although it is definitely the case that calling:

```
SendMessage(tb1.Handle, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, UIS_CLEAR OR UISF_HIDEFOCUS, 0);
```

while the control *has* focus causes the focus rectangle to temporarily re-appear until it loses focus.

**Note**: I only tried it with styles enabled.

Comment: it doesn't work with VCL styles, as mentioned in the description

Answer (score 0):

You can prevent `TTrackBar` from getting focused by setting its `TabStop` property to ˙False`.

When you do this the the dotted line around `TTrackBar` won't ever be shown.

Well the only exception is if you have no other focusable component on the form in which case the dotted line still appears when you start interacting with the trackbar.

EDIT: Right I forgot that VCL Styles override the said property amongst many others.

You could modify your VCL style in a way so you disable the `FocusEffect` for `TTrackBar` and then use this modified style instead.

Comment: disabling TabStop makes no difference when VCL styles are used.